# How to set data into nuxt.js nuxt-link?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, nuxt.js

I'm trying to pass data into nuxt-link but nuxt-link is just returning a 404 error when I click on the link. It doesn't seem to be getting and loading the file....

The second 2 links that use :href and hardcoding works

```html
<template>
  <h2 class="subtitle"><nuxt-link :to="{path: filePath}" exact>Nuxt View Menu</nuxt-link></h2>
  <h2 class="subtitle"><a :href="filePath">Vue View Menu</a></h2>
  <h2 class="subtitle"><a href="files/officialMenu.pdf">HardCode View Menu</a></h2>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  layout: 'default',
  data () {
    return {
      filePath: 'files/officialMenu.pdf'
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Nuxt uses vue-router by reading off the vue-router documentation you'll be able to achieve what you want.

[router-link documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-link-props)

Example below

```html
<!-- named route -->
<nuxt-link :to="{ name: 'user', params: { userId: 123 }}">User</nuxt-link>

<!-- with query, resulting in `/register?plan=private` -->
<nuxt-link :to="{ path: 'register', query: { plan: 'private' }}">Register</nuxt-link>
```

This will be available to your next page in **$route** object as **$route.params** or in the url query as seen above.

Comment: I don't believe this is the case... I'm trying to pass the filePath into nuxt-link... no where does the documentation provide a way to pass a static asset path to the URL.

Comment: Ahh that case you could just use 2nd and 3rd one. Since when we use nuxt-link or router-link it should be something that in reach within the routes you defined.

Comment: Thanks for the commented example; that's what I needed to see.

Answer (score 4):

If you use post way to send data another route in vuejs or nuxtjs.
Here, if route name is = /user
So, you have to write the following nuxt-link

```
<nuxt-link :to="{ name: 'user', params: { userId: 123 }}">User</nuxt-link>
```

and for receive data next componet, means on "/user" route you have to write inside created or any other place and check console.

```
created() {
   console.log(this.$route.params)
   console.log(this.$route.params.userId)
   console.log(this.$nuxt._route.params)
   console.log(this.$nuxt._route.params.userId)
}
```

========================================================
if you use Get way to send data another route in vuejs or nuxtjs.
Here, if route name is = /register
so, you have to write the following nuxt-link

```
<nuxt-link :to="{ path: 'register', query: { plan: 'private' }}">Register</nuxt-link>
```

and for receive data next componet, means on "/register" route you have to write inside created or any other place and check console.

```
created() {
   console.log(this.$route.query)
   console.log(this.$route.query.plan)
   console.log(this.$nuxt._route.query)
   console.log(this.$nuxt._route.query.plan)
}
```

## Now, you can use this data anywhere like data, mounted, method etc...

How to define route name?????

Add the following code into "nuxt.config.js" file to add route name.

```
    router: {
        base: '/',
        extendRoutes(routes, resolve) {
          routes.push({
            name: 'user',
            path: '/user',
            component: resolve(__dirname, 'pages/user.vue')
          })
        }
      },
```

Here,

1. Name property is the name of route that you want to provide as route name.
2. In Path property you have to provide route path.
3. Component property is the component path of that component need to load in this route.